# Python Unshort URL without response.history

Tags: python

Im using this code to unshorten all urls, it works correctly but can't get it to work on this particular one "https://www.shareasale-analytics.com/u.cfm?d=654202&m=52031&u=1363577&shrsl_analytics_sscid=41k4%5F9si0z&shrsl_analytics_sstid=41k4%5F9si0z" --> URL contains aff link

```
    response = requests.get(url, timeout=15)

    if response.history:
        url_new = response.url
```

It simply does not find the final url. The result should be https://www.gearbest.com/other-novelty-lights/pp_009234504925.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirect for this particular URL is being done by JS. This works out well when using browsers, python requests module cannot follow these redirects.

I used POSTMAN to actually find this out in the first place. These are the steps i performed -

1. Used browser (firefox) to verify that redirect does work. -> Worked.
2. Used postman to see the actual response. This is what postman received -

> ```
> <head></head>
>
> <body>
>
>
>   <script LANGUAGE="JavaScript1.2">
>       window.location.replace('https:\/\/www.gearbest.com\/other-novelty-lights\/pp_009234504925.html?wid=1433363&sscid=41k4_9si0z&utm_source=shareasale&utm_medium=shareasale&utm_campaign=shareasale&sascid=41k4_9si0z&userID=1363577')
>   </script>
>
>
> </body>
>
> </html>
> ```

I trimmed the whitespaces from the response.
So it is clear that JS is redirecting this further.

To make this work, you will need to perform 2 steps -

1. Update user agent in headers so that response contains the html with information about JS redirect.
2. Follow the redirect yourself.

Hope, this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're seeing is the redirect is performed via Javascript rather than a regular HTTP redirect; also in order to receive the JS code you need to change your user agent:

```py
import re
import requests

url = "https://www.shareasale-analytics.com/u.cfm?d=654202&m=52031&u=1363577&shrsl_analytics_sscid=41k4%5F9si0z&shrsl_analytics_sstid=41k4%5F9si0z"
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.122 Safari/537.36"}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
if response.history:
    url_new = response.url
else:
    matches = re.findall("window.location.replace\('(.*)'\)", response.content.decode(), re.DOTALL)
    if matches:
        match = matches[0]
        url_new = match.strip().replace("\\", "")
```

After that just retrieve the new URL using a simple regex.